# Lazy-loading in feature modules- Angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, dynamic-feature-module

The app stays here: https://angular-dqpbqa.stackblitz.io. what mistake am i doing? and it also loads heroes-list initially, but the path is ''.

lazyloading of feature modules is not working. i have created separate routing in each feature module. dynamically loading the module using loadchildren property

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard',
  loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => 
mod.DashboardModule)
},
 { path: 'heroes',
  loadChildren: () => import('./heroes/heroes.module').then(mod => 
mod.HeroesModule)
},
{ path: 'detail/:id',
  loadChildren: () => import('./hero-detail/hero-detail.module').then(mod 
=> mod.HeroDetailModule)
},
{
path: '',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full'
},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

stackblitz-editable: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqpbqa

Comment: provide some code of your app

Comment: i had shared the link now

Comment: Please paste the code along with the question - this ensures that the question retains its validity if/when the external link dries out. Also, what doesn't work? What is the expected functionality you are expecting? Please have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HeroesModule is not lazy-loaded because it is imported in `app.module.ts` <= that's the mistake

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ /* ... */ HeroesModule, /* ... */ ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There, HeroesModule is initially loaded and the app has access to the routes of `heroes-routing.module.ts`

So when you navigate to `''`, the path will match the path `''` defined in your `heroes-routing.module.ts` which display the `HeroesComponent`

Comment: yes i am importing all the feature modules in 'app.module.ts', what's wrong in this ? @NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HeroesModule,HeroDetailModule, MessagesModule, AppRoutingModule, DashboardModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [HeroService, MessageService]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: If you import them in ``app.module.ts``, they are eagerly loaded, they are available at initialization.
Remove them (``HeroesModule``, ``HeroDetailModule``, ``DashboardModule``)  from this imports array and they will be lazy-loaded through the ``app-routing.module.ts``

Comment: i had made changes as suggested, but how do i verify my modules lazyloaded, since i don't see 'chunk.js' in network tab.

Comment: It seems that you can't see your chunk via Stackblitz. Check this out on your local machine (I just gave it try and it works, I can see ``mylazy-mylazy-module.js`` in the Network tab when I navigate to my lazy route